# ROS in academia

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I've been taking a look at papers applying ROS to academia/teaching, and dicussing some results of using it, without luck. Do you know about any work about that?

Thank you so much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221831/ros-in-academia/) by [jotaraul](https://answers.ros.org/users/9056/jotaraul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2015-12-01**:
"applying ROS to academia/teaching" in what sense? and what do you mean by "results of using it"?

**Comment by [jotaraul](https://answers.ros.org/users/9056/jotaraul/) on 2015-12-01**:
I meant to use ROS for teaching robotic topics like robot navigation, localization, etc. In other words, you explain the theory behind some algorithms, and use their implementations in ROS to see how they work in simulation or with real robots. And by "results of using it", its effect on students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are lots of people teaching courses based on ROS.

Several of them have posted their course websites here: http://wiki.ros.org/Courses

Also I suggest that you might want to reach out the the ROS SIG for Education: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-education to get more information.

Edit:
There are also a lot of citations of the [original ROS paper](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=0Ix7S-4AAAAJ&citation_for_view=0Ix7S-4AAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C)

And the new [ROS 2 paper](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&citation_for_view=0Ix7S-4AAAAJ:kNdYIx-mwKoC)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2